# $\mathbb{E}[X_{n}\mid \mathcal{F}_n]$ does not converge in probability to $0$.

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space.

Give an example of a sequence of positive random variables $\left(X_n\right)_{n\ge 1}$ and  a sequence $\left(\mathcal{F}_n\right)_{n\ge 1} $ of sub-tribes of $\mathcal{F}$  such that $X_n$ converges in probability to $0$ and that  $\mathbb{E}[X_{n}\mid \mathcal{F}_n]$ does not converge in probability to $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mathcal F_n =\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ for all $n$ then $E(X|\mathcal F_n)=EX_n$. So all you need is a positive sequence $(X_n)$ with finite mean converging to $0$ in probability with $EX_n$ not converging to $0$. Can you find such an example?

Comment: No,  i can't find such an example

Comment: Take any disjoint sequence of events $(A_n)$ with positive measures tending to 0 and divide $I_{A_n}$ by the measure of $(A_n)$.

Comment: Why  $E(X_n|\mathcal F_n)=E(X_n)$ ?

Comment: @GagaNao Because $E(X|\mathcal G)=EX$ when $X$ is independent of $\mathcal G$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})=([0,1],\mathcal{B}, \lambda)$, with the latter denoting the Borel algebra and the measure $\lambda$.

Let $X_n= n 1_{[0,1/n]}.$ Then, $X_n$ clearly converges to $0$ in probability and is positive and bounded (hence, admits a conditional expectation). Let $\mathcal{F}_n=\{\emptyset, [0,1]\}$ for each $n$. Then, $\mathbb{E}(X_n|\mathcal{F}_n)=\mathbb{E}(X_n)=1,$ which clearly doesn't go to $0$.

Comment: The sequence of random variables $X_n$ in probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}) $ ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.